# Hold to display image on GridView [Android]

Tags: android, gridview

**The Goal:**

I have a GridView with images. My goal is to display the image full screen while the user is pressing down on the image (with a 1-second delay from moment he presses and holds to display time), when the user releases his finger off the screen the image should no longer be displayed.

**The Issue:**

- Only the top left item (image icon) in the GridView is responding to
  the long hold however the incorrect position is being fired off thus
  the incorrect image being show.
- No other items in GridView are
  responding to the long hold, instead the ACTION_MOVE is firing for
  them.
- Even when moving within the first item/image in the GridView,
  the long hold is firing even though it should not because of the
  clause within the ACTION_MOVE

**The Code:**

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, final MotionEvent event) {

                final float SCROLL_THRESHOLD = 300;

                //Thread to show image after 1 second of holding
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (showImage == true) {
                            //The user has held the screen for one second and is still holding the screen thus show image
                            int position = gridView.pointToPosition((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                            showFullImage(position);
                        }
                    }
                };

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        isOnClick = true;
                        showImage = true;
                        //To show image after one second of hold delay:
                        handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 1000);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (isOnClick && (Math.abs(mDownX - (int) event.getX()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD || Math.abs(mDownY - (int) event.getY()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD)) {
                            //User is scrolling gridView, not long holding thus don't show full image
                            showImage = false;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                            gridView.onTouchEvent(event);
                            removeDisplayImage(); //Removes image and shows layout
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                        if (isOnClick && (Math.abs(mDownX - (int) event.getX()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD || Math.abs(mDownY - (int) event.getY()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD)) {
                            //User is scrolling gridView, not long holding thus don't show full image
                            showImage = false;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                            gridView.onTouchEvent(event);
                            removeDisplayImage(); //Removes image and shows layout
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (isOnClick) {
                            showImage = false;
                            handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
                            removeDisplayImage(); //Removes image and shows layout
                            return true;
                        }
                        break; 

                    default:
                        gridView.onTouchEvent(event);
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I should also mention that I'm okay with alternative solutions/code that I may use. I'm not dead set on my current path. Also, if you would like to better visualize what I'm attempting to do imagine the way SnapChat was: a ListView where you must hold to view the media and let go to stop, only with a 1-second delay added. Thank you.